# How to compare id's in two different models In Node Js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-modules

I have model `answerlist` which has `ownerId` and `answeredBy` objects containing `ownerId`.
I want to fetch `answerlist`'s data where `ownerId = answeredBy.ownerId`.
Don't know how to do it in sequelize.

Following is my code

```
db.answersList.findAll({
          include: [
           { model: db.Employee, as: 'answeredBy', attributes: ['id', 'ownerId']},
           { model: db.Owner, as: 'owner',attributes: ['id']}
          ],
          want to do something like where:{'answeredBy.ownerId':'owner.id'} 
});
```

Comment: I think you need to associate it first? http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html in your models so that you can do anwerList.answerBy (when you include)

Comment: already did that but 'answeredBy.ownerId' ==  'owner.id' gives column not found error

Comment: What is the exact structure of your `answerList` table? Do you have both `ownerId` and `answeredById` columns there?

Comment: AnswerList table contains ownerId and answeredById as foreign keys. ownerId 
 is of Owner table & answeredById  is of Employee table primary key. Employee also have OwnerId in it.